Why rsync fails with broken pipe?
I tried to rerun few times this command, but it fails all the time with error:
...
debug1: Sending command: rsync --server -vlogDtpAXrxe.iLsfxCIvu --log-format=%i --delete --append --append . /path/sdc/sdc
sending incremental file list
<f.stp.g... sdc
747.485.003.776  37%  116,81MB/s    2:54:34  packet_write_wait: Connection to IP port 22: Broken pipe

rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)

I discovered, that I had different versions on sender/receiver. I installed the same, but it still fails.
How to resolve the issue?
Could I use better options to copy 2TB disk?

Is network connectivity between your two hosts usually good, or does it sometimes break? If you run with --partial, then it would be easy to restart the copy.  Are you copying the actual device file? Are all partitions on the disk unmounted?

@Kusalananda. Yes, I am using --partial I already restarted task two times. It reaches 747GB and issues Broken pipe error message. Exactly at the same position. During the time of error I have the ssh connection to the sender host. It is not broken. Yes, I am copying actual device. It is not mounted at all.
